# How to get the smallest (earliest) possible Date value

Tags: datetime

I am trying to get the smallest possible value for date (ie, the earliest date). If I were using Java, I would do something like this:

```
new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1743994/377384)

I could do something like [this](http://www.salesforcefast.com/2009/06/getting-min-or-max-from-soql.html), but that seems like a lot of extra work. I could also just hard code the value like this: `datetime.newInstance(-99999999999L);`, because I think that is the smallest `Long` value possible... But that is not the nicest thing.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to get the earliest possible date?

Comment: @DanielHoechst, two reasons: 1. I want a default date when searching (when there is no input), and 2. Because I want to know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I question the validity of what you're doing, since I've never seen this to be necessary, but since you asked, from [the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm):

> The earliest valid date is 1700-01-01T00:00:00Z GMT, or just after midnight on January 1, 1700. The latest valid date is 4000-12-31T00:00:00Z GMT, or just after midnight on December 31, 4000.

So therefore to construct the earliest possible date, you'd do something like

```
Date myDate = date.newinstance(1700, 1, 1);
```

(Untested but it should work. Also, probably irrelevant but your Java example is constructing a very late date, not a very early date.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is similar to my hard coded example (min value of `Long`). I was hoping there would be a better answer than a hard coded value (in the `max` case to avoid the dreaded Y4K bug - you may be laughing now...). But it does seem like there is no nice way to get it. Thanks for the note too about the java example, I have modified my question. I would like to leave this question open for some time in case anyone has a better answer. But I will mark this as the answer if nobody has anything better. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a number / string / undefined when creating a date object. When passing a number as parameter, it means how many milliseconds since the very first date (1970-01-01 08:00:00). So if you pass 0 as the parameter you can get the smallest possible value for date.

```
new Date(0)
```